# Can't get parmalink from Wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i want to fetch all post and insert into custom table but i can't get **url (Parmalink)** of post but it's always null or get error.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(  "showposts" => 50));
global $wpdb;
foreach($posts as $post) 
{
      $wpdb->insert('wp_employee', array('pottitle'=>$post->post_title, 'postid'=>$post->ID, , 'postid'=>$post->permalink), array('%s', '%s', '%s'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know if any issue ;)

```
function getp($s)
    {
        $result = post_permalink( $s );
        return $result;
    }
```

Call the function

```
$posts = get_posts(array(  "showposts" => 50));
global $wpdb;
foreach($posts as $post) 
{
      $wpdb->insert('wp_employee', array('pottitle'=>$post->post_title, 'postid'=>$post->ID,  'postid'=>$post->getp($post->ID)), array('%s', '%s', '%s'));
}
```

Also you can call direct with using post_permalink

```
'lastname'=>post_permalink($post->ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_posts()` does not return value like permalink

try to check http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

so you need to make manually permalink with postid or use `get_permalink()` or `the_permalink()`

Comment: yes it is possible wiwh postid i try it but i got error :( 
get_permalink($post->ID)

Comment: try the_permalink() ?

Comment: try the post_permalink($post->ID)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line inside the foreach loop

```
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
```

and use $permalink wherever you want in foreach loop